# ExtJS connection with SQL Server using C#.net

Tags: extjs4.1

I have created a form and grid using ExtJS 4.1.1 for insert, update, delete in MVC pattern in Visual Studio 2010. I want to perform these CRUD task with SQL Server (I have created the procedure) but I have no idea that how can I use ExtJS with SQL Server and C#. Even in Sencha web there is tutorial for PHP and MySQL only.

Thus, I am looking to connect ExtJS with SQL. I need step by step tutorial and guide that I can complete my official project.

Comment: Read about [ASP.NET WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

Answer (score 0):

Ext JS is a server-agnostic UI framework... so while some of the examples you have seen are in PHP with MySQL, it ultimately doesn't affect the JavaScript code. For example, the REST proxy:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Rest

This proxy (like all proxies in Ext JS) connects to a remote data service. That service sends/receives XML, JSON, or some other data format.

What the remote data service (written in .NET, PHP, Java, or anything else) does with the data once it's been received has nothing to do with Ext JS.

It sounds to me like you need a tutorial for writing web services in C#.